# How to filter a csv file based on datetime?

Tags: python, csv, datetime

I have a csv file which looks like this (obviously in reality its much bigger):

```
1,$1,AA,GG,DD,2020-01-01T00:01:10.740+02:00
2,$2,A1,FD,HH,2020-01-01T00:02:00.240+02:00
3,$3,1A,PP,LL,2020-01-01T00:03:30.460+02:00
4,$4,S1,LL,SS,2020-02-01T00:01:11.190+02:00
5,$5,2G,PP,FF,2020-01-01T00:04:20.320+02:00
6,$6,5S,LL,TT,2020-02-01T01:02:15.180+02:00
```

I need to take the first row, take that date and check whether the rest of the rows are equal to that day and between `0:00:00.000` hour AND `23:59:59.999` hour. So to say it simple.. I take all the rows inside the date of the first row.

This is my desired outcome:

```
1,$1,AA,GG,DD,2020-01-01T00:01:10.740+02:00
2,$2,A1,FD,HH,2020-01-01T00:02:00.240+02:00
3,$3,1A,PP,LL,2020-01-01T00:03:30.460+02:00
5,$5,2G,PP,FF,2020-01-01T00:04:20.320+02:00
```

This is my code:

```
root = r'c:\data\FF\Desktop\my_files\file01.txt'

with open(root, 'r') as my_file:
    reader = csv.reader(my_file)
        
def filter_row():
    for row in reader:
        date_time = row[5]   #<--- extract the datetime 
        fdate_time = datetime.strptime(date_time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z') #<--- make a datetime object of it
        x = fdate_time.date() #<--- extract the y/m/d

        begin_time = datetime.strptime(x + '00:00.00+02:00','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z') #<--- fix the start time of a day
        end_time = datetime.strptime(x + '23:59:59.999+02:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z') #<--- fix the end time of a day
        
        filtered_records = fdate_time >= begin_time and fdate_time <= end_time #<filter everything between the start and end time
        
    return filtered_records
        
filter_row()
```

When I run above code I receive:

```
  File "C:\data\FF\Desktop\Python\My_python\Filter_csv.py", line 82, in filter_row
    for row in reader:

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

I really lost it as I don't know how to fix this. I looked for multiple solutions but couldn't find any. Hope someone can tell and show me how it works. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

The context management provided by `with` ensure that the resources are freed at end of block. That mean that everything should be read *inside* the `with` bloc.

A simple way would be to parameterize the function:

```
root = r'c:\data\FF\Desktop\my_files\file01.txt'

def filter_row(reader):
    for row in reader:
        ...            
    return filtered_records

with open(root, 'r') as my_file:
    reader = csv.reader(my_file)
    filter_row(reader)
```

But:

- you should use the `datetime.replace` method to compute the start and end of the day instead of using strings
- if you want to write the lines to a new file, you should change `filter row` into a generator:

```py
root = r'c:\data\FF\Desktop\my_files\file01.txt'
newf= r'c:\data\FF\Desktop\my_files\file01.csv'

def filter_row(reader):
    first = True
    for row in reader:
        date_time = row[5]  # <--- extract the datetime
        fdate_time = datetime.strptime(date_time, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')  # <--- make a datetime object of it

        if first:         # special processing for the first line
            first = False
            begin_time = fdate_time.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) # <--- fix the start time of a day
            end_time = fdate_time.replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59, microsecond=999999) # <--- fix the end time of a day
            yield row      # yield first row
        elif fdate_time >= begin_time and fdate_time <= end_time:  # <filter everything between the start and end time
            yield row      # and rows of same date

with open(root) as my_file, open(newf, 'w', newline=None) as new_file:
    reader = csv.reader(my_file)
    writer = csv.writer(new_file)

    writer.writerows(filter_row(reader))
```

Comment: I receive the following error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.date' and 'str'`

Comment: @NorthAfrican What do you want to do with the filtered rows? Directly process them with another function, or write them to a new file?

Comment: Bellesta, write them to a new file

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you doing it using pandas.

1. Read the file using pandas in dataframe
2. Then restrict the rows to first value of date (filter the records and put in different data frame)
3. New data frame will have the desired output

Pandas will give you easy scalability too in case in future your file size increases.

Comment: I though about pandas but I have to many records so pandas would get stuck

Comment: Please use chunksize while reading using pandas and then play with the data, hopefully it will not stuck.